# MongoDB Scala Async Driver

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'm evaluating the MongoDB async driver:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver

The API looks pretty simply, but how could I do the following transformation?

```
val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("test")
```

I would like to do an implicit transformation when I do CRUD operations on the database. I could not find enough information in the reference documentation on how to do an implicit transformation.

Could anyone point me to any reference on how to do an implicit transformation?

Comment: What do you mean by implicit transformation?

Comment: I mean instead of getting a Document type back, I get a User type back when I call database.getCollection("user"), where User is a case class that represents the underlying user document in MongoDB!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scala driver is only a thin wrapper around the java driver rather than a pure implementation :( ... so you have to follow the java driver's conventions and provide a codec.  I don't have a working example, but you should be able to follow this: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.3/bson/codecs/ and register a codec for a scala class.